# Simplify powershell query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am learning powershell, and a looking to query couple of AD groups and determine whether  a user is member of AD group.

- Part 1 : Query a AD group which has 10 nested AD groups
- Part 2: Query user's AD group and pull a list
- Part 3: Not posted, but to compare output of Part 1 and Part 2

Searched online and found some tits and bits. I am aware of Active Directory module, but avoid using it, since this script would be executed by user who is non-technical and avoid installing RSAT just for that.

I have Powershell version 2 and Windows 7

## Part 1

group1 is the AD group which has 10 nested AD groups.

```
Write-Host "Fetching information from groups.Please wait.."
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$group=[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity  ($ct,'group1')
$group1 = $group.GetMembers | Where {$_.StructuralObjectClass -eq "group"} | Select    SamAccountName
$group1 = $group1 -replace("=", " ") -replace("{", " ") -replace("@", " ") -replace ("}", " ") -replace("SamAccountname", " ")  -replace '\s+', ' '
$ADGroups = foreach ($l in group1) {$l.trim()}
```

To ensure the AD group information is fetched by program or exit the script

```
if (($ADgroups | out-string) -like $null) {
  Write-Host "Unable to fetch AD groups information" -foreground "red"
  Start-sleep 10
  break 
}
```

## Part 2

Temp location where files can be written

```
$location = "C:\AD"
$ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($ct, $username)
If ($user -like $null) {
  Write-host "User does not exist in AD" -foreground "magenta"
  start-sleep 10
  break
}
Write-Host "Please wait...Looking user group membership..."
$usergroups = $user.GetGroups()
```

Removing file if exists.

```
Remove-Item $location\useradgroups.txt
$usergroups | select SamAccountName | Out-File $location\useradgroups.txt -append
$testr = gc $location\useradgroups.txt
if (($testr | out-string) -like $null) {
  Write-Host "Unable to fetch user AD groups   information" -foreground "red"
  Start-sleep 10
  Remove-Item $location\useradgroups.txt
  break
}
$useradgroups = foreach ($l in $testr ) {$l.trim()}
$useradgroups | Select-String -Pattern "\w" | out-file $location\useradgroups.txt
$useradgroups = gc $location\useradgroups.txt
```

Question:

Unless I trim the output, cannot compare it. so had to write the script as shown above:

1. Avoid writting the output to text file
2. Avoid `-replace("=", " ") -replace("{", " ")` in Part 1
3. Simplify the code.

Any suggestion from Powershell gurus would be welcomed. It would help me in learning process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're trying to do is recursively get ADGroupMembers? Sort of like [this](http://poshcode.org/4181) or [this](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/05/23/pstip-retrieve-group-membership-of-an-active-directory-group-recursively/#comment-906454177)? There is always more than one way to do things. [You can use the `[ASDI]` type accelerator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx).

```
$groups = [adsi]'LDAP://CN=GroupName,OU=Groups,OU=Place,DC=Tomorrow,DC=Today'
$group | Get-Member 
foreach($group in $groups){
    $members = $group.member
    foreach($member in $members){
        #Is this a group or a user?
        #If group Get the Group members
        #If a user say the user is part of the group
    }
}
```

Are you trying to format the distinguishedName of a user?

```
$user = "CN=Huck Finn,OU=Users,OU=Today,OU=Tomorrow,DC=Yesterday,DC=com"
$splits = ($user -split ',')
[PSCustomObject]@{Username=$splits[0].substring(3);OUPath=($splits[1..($splits.Count-1)] | % {$_.substring(3)}) -join '\'}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to fetch 10 AD groups nested under GROUP1. If a user is a member of any 10 nested groups, it should display username and name of group it is member of. So for e.g if Bob is member of GROUP A  which is nested under GROUP1, it should display "Bob is member of Group A". I will try your solution tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thanks BoblobLaw. The script you gave to query Group1, works and displays all group members and show Distinguished name of all Group members as output. $user variable is the login id of the user. So if I type my loginid / samaccountname, it should pull out my user group information and compare with the Part1 output.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but can't you use something like this for part 1?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADGroupMember "group1" | select sAMAccountName
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works with AD module, which I would like to avoid. I am comparing user's membership with one master AD Group, which as 10 nested AD groups. If a user is member of any one of 10 AD groups, the group name and username should be displayed as output